# CloudFormation template with an SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to create a template using CloudFormation.
I've done it without CF but in order to keep going for the project, I need it to do it with CF.

What I am trying to achieve is a Lambda that retrieves files and put them into a S3 bucket, an SNS topic that will trigger another lambda once there is a change on the S3 bucket.

Seems pretty simple but I am new to AWS and still working on it. This is what I've done so far.

```yaml
  
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 15

Resources:

  # S3 Bucket
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  # Functions
  DataTransformer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Description: Function that is called when a file is stored in S3.
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        S3Bucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            
  DataRetriever:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Description: Function that is called when a file is stored in S3.
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        S3Bucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'

  # Permissions
  DataTransformerPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref DataTransformer
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn

  DataRetrieverPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref DataRetriver
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn
```

Comment: can you share what's the trouble you are facing or the error message??

Comment: Well, the next step is adding the SNS but I am not sure if this is the correct way to write the template as I am double checking on the designer.

Comment: Why do you need an SNS topic? you can trigger with S3 Event directly. You can use S3 Event

Comment: Once Lambda execution complete you can trigger SNS by using destination feature in lambda. https://github.com/aviboy2006/lambda-apigateway-sns-cnf-awsugblrdemo/blob/main/sample.yaml see this example

Comment: You can configure S3 to trigger lambda directly with a notification: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-notification

Comment: You are using SAM, so you can also define the trigger as an event source for the lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html